# Is it possible to shrink the space surrounding a SwiftUI grid?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I noticed when building a small `LazyHGrid` (5 * 5 of squares) the total width of the grid was flush to the squares. However, the vertical was completely unbounded. I don't want it to fill the entire vertical bound so I tried a bunch of different ways such as `.scaleToFit` and others but nothing worked to shrink fit the grid to the squares.

I'm guessing maybe this just isn't made to be because grids in SwiftUI weren't intended for such a purpose but it seems odd. I know that the grids can be bounded by using a `.frame()` but that feels like a band-aid solution to me.

Is it possible to bound a grid's outer spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you just need fixed size, like below (tested with Xcode 12.0 / iOS 14)

```
LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 200, maximum: 200))]) {

  // content here

}.fixedSize()    // << here !!
```